# Unexpected behavior when appending objects to Javascript lists

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

Working with latest Google chrome, I'm running the following code:

```
(data) => {  //data is a list of json tuples that look like [{x: __, y: ___}, ...]
    var rand = () => Math.random() * data.length;

    const placeholder = [...Array(10).keys()].map(_ => {
      const idx = Math.floor(rand());
      return data[idx];
    });
};
```

What I would expect this function to do is to sample a 10-subset of input data and return it in the same format. On every iteration in the map function, I am printing out the object and it looks as expected (see image). What's weird is that then then result I see in the "placeholder" array has every Release_Date key being the same value as placeholder[0]['Release_Date'], when they should each be unique values. The Production_Budget looks fine. I don't know what's going on here and I'm stumped. Does anyone have any idea as to what's happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your function never return anything.

```js
const getSample = (data) => { //data is a list of json tuples that look like [{x: __, y: ___}, ...]
  const rand = () => Math.random() * data.length;

  const placeholder = [...Array(10).keys()].map(_ => {
    const idx = Math.floor(rand());
    return data[idx];
  });
  
  /* | | | | | | | */
  /* V V V V V V V */
  return placeholder;
};

const data = Array(30).fill(0).map(() => ({
  x: Math.random.between(0, 600),
  y: Math.random.between(0, 600),
}));

const sample = getSample(data);
console.log(sample);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/olian04/better-random/src/index.js"></script>
```

You could also simplify your code quite a bit, if wanted too. For example:

```js
const getSample = (data, sampleSize=10) => Array(sampleSize).fill(0)
  .map(() => Math.random.select(data));

const data = Array(30).fill(0).map(() => ({
  x: Math.random.between(0, 600),
  y: Math.random.between(0, 600),
}));

const sample = getSample(data);
console.log(sample);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/olian04/better-random/src/index.js"></script>
```